# How to get a software's license details and the expiration of the installed software in windows using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, odoo, winreg

I have been using python 3x and I need to get the installed softwares details like license and the expiration of the license data details. I have used winreg library and subprocess to get the version details but not the license details. How to achieve that?

Comment: What makes you think that it is mandatory for the software manufacturer to store the license information in any kind of standardized location?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I too thought that, but is that possible to get the expiration date of the license?.

Comment: Perhaps some retarded software keeps the expiration date on your machine (where you could easily "extend" your license by editing the value). But these days you have your license key on your machine and it's validity is checked online with the API endpoint.